# Recreate Window Using GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo Method

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I believe that the `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` method gets information about the window passed as a parameter into it into a `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` structure. Can this information be used to recreate a window? Or is there a method which can create a window taking `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

There is no function that I know of that will create a new window given a `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` structure. There certainly isn't such a thing described in the [Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference.

I'd be interested to know why you want such a thing. Are you trying to create a duplicate console window? If so, you should note that a process can be associated with only one console. And you can't create a console window that's not attached to a process. The console goes away when the last process detaches from it.

Comment: Sir, I have a swf running in a window. It has been embedded into a window. I was trying to capture the window content and duplicate it into another window. And i was looking and the solution other than the Bitblt functiion.